# How do I align (and keep aligned) the content of my pages (i.e., titles, headers, images, briefs) to my logo that is top left of every page?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

This is the navbar used for each page which also contains my logo:

```
<header>
    <a class="logo" href="#">My<span>Name</span></a>
    <nav>
        <ul class="navlinks">
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the css:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navlinks {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

I would like to align all my pages' content to the logo in my navbar(top left) and have it "stick" on the same vertical line that my logo is on when the page size is adjusted.

For reference on how I would like my website to work/emulate behavior: http://www.roywilhelm.com

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Do you mean that your logo and page content should have the same distance from the left side of the viewport? You can place everything in a container (or use the body) to do this. I think we need more code (e.g. some the page content) to understand your issue.

Comment: Can you add a rough picture of how you want the styling to be?

Comment: Thank you! I am new to front-end and I appreciate all the help. Yes, that is exactly what I mean; my logo and page content should have the same distance from the left side of the viewport (for the logo, same distance from the top as well). I've added a couple of screenshots to provide context but I'm not sure if they're visible; I used the images button and added the links. Someone please let me know if they're not visible.

Comment: When I put everything in a container, it works but now my navbar link(s) is moved over to the left underneath my logo.

Answer (score 1):

use a container class

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-inline: auto;
}
header .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navlinks {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href="#">My<span>Name</span></a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="navlinks">
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
</div>
```